# Handling Two Query Strings with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string, clean-urls

I'm trying to rewrite urls for a page that has two query strings parameter. And according to these parameters value (set or not), I show different contents on the page.

```
example.com/fotograf.php?aid=10
example.com/fotograf.php?aid=10&fid=5
```

The URLs above are the examples to not rewrited ones. I just want to make them such that

```
example.com/fotograf/10/
example.com/fotograf/10/5/
```

The first URL links to the album with photos, and the second one links to a photo in that album.

In `.htaccess`, I just want to be able to reach them with the clean URLs above. After that, I will check the URL at the top of the script and if it's not clean then with a function I wrote I will redirect it to clean one (by getting values with preg_match and preg_split and redirecting with header function).

So far, I have tried this rule (which did not work to view album):

```
RewriteRule ^fotograf/([0-9-/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ fotograf.php?aid=$1&fid=$2 [L]
```

Then, this (which redirects to album always):

```
RewriteRule ^fotograf/([0-9-/]+)/?$ fotograf.php?aid=$1 [L]
```

Finally, this (helped me to view the photo by a URL like `example.com/fotograf/10/?fid=5`):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fid=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^fotograf/(.*)/$ fotograf.php?aid=$1&fid=%1
```

But I don't want to see any question marks or ampersands in the URL.

Somehow, I need to check which one(s) is(are) set and redirect accordingly but I just don't know how to achieve this.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your application to generate the URLs like you want them, so in the form:

```
example.com/fotograf/10/
example.com/fotograf/10/5/
```

and following rewrite rule will make sure, it'll reach your php:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^fotograf/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ fotograf.php?aid=$1&fid=$2

RewriteRule ^fotograf/([0-9]+)/?$ fotograf.php?aid=$1
```

`mod_rewrite` can't rewrite URLs in your HTML pages...

Comment: Actually, I must have tried what you suggested but I think it was the opposite order, which might have changed the behaviour of the code. Now it's working!

I'm generating these URLs at the top of the each page via a function in which I first recognize the query string and then I split them and get their values to generate the clean versions. Finally with the header function, I redirect to the new clean URL without printing something on the page. I don't know if my approach is efficient but I couldn't do it in .htaccess I had to deal with it with PHP.

Thanks a lot @Kamil Šrot

Comment: @Gungor you'r approach is fine. From where are coming the "unclean" URLs? You can also try to get rid of them completelly

Comment: For testing purposes I'm still keeping them in the pages, especially in the menu. When I'm sure that I'm doing it correct, I will change all of them to clean ones.

Answer (score 1):

```
# this works 
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /yourdir/yourfolder/

# only 1 in root 
# RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?act=$1[L,QSA]

  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ members.php?act=$1&opts=$2

  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ members.php?act=$1

 #   Your url would be:
 #   example of http://localhost/yourdir/yourfolder/members.php?act=beer
 #   http://localhost/yourdir/yourfolder/beer
 # or 
 # http://localhost/yourdir/yourfolder/members.php?act=beer&ops=morebeer
 # http://localhost/yourdir/yourfolder/beer/morebeer
```